# Form to redirect to a sub-domain depending on user input

Tags: javascript, forms, forward

I need to put together a form script to redirect the user based on what is entered into the form. I understand this can be done from JavaScript, I managed to put something together but it didn't do quite what I wanted it to do which is

User enters text, for example mysubdomain, then hits submit.

I would then like them to be forwarded to mysubdomain.mydomain.com. 
I managed to do the opposite so it directed to mydomain.com/mysubdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
<form onsubmit="window.location='http://'+this.subdomain.value+'.mydomain.com/';
 return false">
<input type="text" name="subdomain" value="" />
</form>
```

using same domain as you are on ([details about the location object here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)): and assuming the form is on xxxx.mydomain.com

```
<form 
onsubmit="window.location='http://'+
this.subdomain.value+
location.hostname.substring(location.hostname.indexOf('.'))'; 
return false">
<input type="text" name="subdomain" value="" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have a function that reloads the entered subdomain by the user + your domain so like `window.location.assign(subdomain + ".yourdomain.com")`

Take a look at the [Location object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) as well.